# How does Spark Streaming's countByValueAndWindow work?

Tags: spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming application that is processing a stream of website click events. Each event has a property containing a GUID that identifies the user session that the event belongs to.

My application is counting up the number of events that occurred for each session, using windowing:

```
def countEvents(kafkaStream: DStream[(String, Event)]): DStream[(String, Session)] = {

  // Get a list of the session GUIDs from the events
  val sessionGuids = kafkaStream
    .map(_._2)
    .map(_.getSessionGuid)

  // Count up the GUIDs over our sliding window
  val sessionGuidCountsInWindow = sessionGuids.countByValueAndWindow(Seconds(60), Seconds(1))

  // Create new session objects with the event count
  sessionGuidCountsInWindow
    .map({
      case (guidS, eventCount) =>
        guidS -> new Session().setGuid(guidS).setEventCount(eventCount)
  })
}
```

My understanding was that the countByValueAndWindow function is only counting the values in the DStream on which the function is called. In other words, in the code above, the call to countByValueAndWindow should return the event counts only for the session GUIDs in the sessionGuids DStream on which we're calling that function.

But I'm observing something different; the call to countByValueAndWindow is returning counts for session GUIDs that are not in sessionGUIDs. It appears to be returning counts for session GUIDs that were processed in previous batches. Am I just misunderstanding how this function works? I haven't been able to find anything in the way of useful documentation online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine who is much more versed in the ways of Spark than I has helped me with this. Apparently I was mis-understanding the way that the countByValueAndWindow function works. I thought that it would only return counts for values in the DStream for which you're calling the function. But, in fact, it returns counts for all values across the entire window. To address my issue, I simply perform a join between my input DStream and the DStream resulting from the countByValueAndWindow operation. Thus I only end up with results for values in my input DStream.